# Error finding Nearest point in vector in R spDist

Tags: r, r-sp

I want to find the nearest point of two dataframes of vectors using sp package

```
location <- c('RODELILLO','RAPEL','QUINTA NORMAL')
lat <-c(-33.03711,-33.93225,-33.43165)
lon <- c(-71.58291,-71.73317,-70.68254)
est <- data.frame(location,lat,lon)

id <- c(1,5,8)
lat2 <- c(-32.59830, -33.54318, -33.54318)
lon2 <- c(-72.034, -71.096, -70.158)
pred <- data.frame(id,lat2,lon2)

est.sp <- SpatialPoints(list(est$lat,est$lon))
pred.sp <- SpatialPoints(list(pred$lat,pred$lon))
```

I tried using spDists function of sp package

```
est$near <- apply(spDists(est.sp,pred.sp, longlat = TRUE), 1, which.min)
```

but it returns an error

```
>In spDists(est.sp, pred.sp, longlat = TRUE) :
   spDists: argument longlat conflicts with CRS(x); using the value TRUE
```

When I delete the longlat argument it works

```
est$near <- apply(spDists(est.sp,pred.sp, longlat = TRUE), 1, which.min)
>       location       lat       lon near
1     RODELILLO -33.03711 -71.58291    1
2         RAPEL -33.93225 -71.73317    2
3 QUINTA NORMAL -33.43165 -70.68254    2
```

but I dont know if its working right, considering my points as latitude longitude pair. Can I have some advices ? Thanks

Comment: why is near having values like 1,2? can you explain a little what is it?

Comment: near have the id of elements in pred data frame